# How to (efficiently) compute the sum of the digits of evey number lying between two given numbers?

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

Given two integers A and B , how to efficiently compute the sum of all the digits of every number int the set  $\{N | A \le N \le B \} $.

For example: **A = 100**  and **B = 777**, then the required answer is **8655**.

I am interested in deriving an formula/efficient algorithm for the same.

Answer (score 7):

You should find the formula $f(n)$ for the sum of digits for numbers from 1 to n, then do $f(B)-f(A)$.  It is not very clean.  The sum of digits of all k digit numbers, that is from $10^{(k-1)} \text { to } 10^k-1$, is $45*(10^k-1)/9$.  Stopping part way is harder, but you can do it by recursion.  If you want the sum of digits of numbers up to $7655$, say, you can do sum of digits up to $999$, plus $1000*6*5/2$ (for the thousands digits up through 6) + $6*$sum of digits up to $999$ (for the last three digits for $1000$ through $6999$) + $7*656$ (for the thousands in the $7$s) + sum of digits up to $655.$  The last has one less digit, so you just call your subroutine with that.

Comment: +1, seems a feasible approach but I haven't understood it fully,could you explain in lucid manner ?

Comment: If you look at the answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8576/number-of-digits-from-1-to-n/8577#8577 you will see a more detailed explanation for the total number of digits in the n digit numbers.  Then you have to deal with the partial decade.  Do you have a specific question on that?

Comment: There's more information in Sloane's A037123.

Comment: @Quixotic see this for a part of your solution. http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-sum-of-digits-in-numbers-from-1-to-n/

Answer (score 2):

Code in C++

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
long long  b,i,x,v,c,ans,anc;
int j,k,a[20];
main(){

    // freopen("a.in","r",stdin);
   //  freopen("a.out","w",stdout);

     cin>>b;
     k=0; x=1; j=0;
     while(b!=0) {a[k]=b%10; b/=10; k++;} for (i=1; i<k; i++) x*=10; if (k==0) x=0; //cout<<x<<" ";
k--;
     while(x!=0) {
        v=45*(x/10)*k;
        c=(a[k]*(a[k]-1)/2)*x+v*a[k]+a[k];
        ans+=j*a[k]*x+c; j+=a[k];
        x/=10; k--;

     }  //cout<<ans<<" ";
     ans-=j;

   cin>>b;
      k=0; x=1; j=0;
     while(b!=0) {a[k]=b%10; b/=10; k++;} for (i=1; i<k; i++) x*=10; //cout<<x;
k--;
     while(x!=0) {
        v=45*(x/10)*k; //cout<<"v=="<<v<<" ";
        c=(a[k]*(a[k]-1)/2)*x+v*a[k]+a[k]; //cout<<"c=="<<c<<" ";
        anc+=j*a[k]*x+c;  j+=a[k]; //cout<<"anc=="<<anc<<" ";
        x/=10; k--; //cout<<endl;

     }



      cout<<anc-ans;

}
```

Comment: Your code seems to work fine on my machine, but perhaps you could add an explanation as to why it works?

Comment: Also FYI, this question appears to be a Spoj contest problem (see [this](http://www.spoj.com/problems/CPCRC1C/)).

Answer (score -1):

Just summing them altogether first would produce a number that has the same `digit-sum` as stringing them altogether.

For example: 101-103

101, 102, 103 -> 1+0+1+1+0+2+1+0+3 -> 9

101+102+103 = 306 = 3+0+6 = 9

Use the Gauss method to add the numbers quickly...
That is, if I have the numbers in a set like 1-10
1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10 = 1+10+2+9+3+8+4+7+5+6 = (1+10)+(2+9)+(3+8)+(4+7)+(5+6) = (11)+(11)+(11)+(11)+(11) = 11*(10/2) <--- 10 is the upper-limit of the given range.

Then add the digits together by dividing by 10 and adding the remainder to one storing variable. (ex. 52 = 5+2 = 7.... 52 --> 52/10 --> 5r2... "2"+? .... 5/10 = 0r5 --> "2"+"5" = 7.)